# How to use FileSystemEntity.watch() in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm building a desktop application, mainly for Windows platform. I want to track events like create, delete in a directory using flutter. I came across the  FileSystemEntity.watch() method but I'm unable to implement that. Can someone share the full example codebase for watching a directory?

Comment: What platform are you on?  That apparently influences what kinds of events you get back, and whether you can watch recursively.

Comment: I'm building desktop application. Mainly for Windows, later develop for linux systems

Answer (score 3):

Just `watch` the folder to receive a stream of events. Normally, you then `listen` to the stream to receive each event as it happens.

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  final tempFolder = File('D:\\temp');
  tempFolder.watch().listen((event) {
    print(event);
  });
}
```

Prints:

```
FileSystemCreateEvent('D:\temp\New Text Document.txt')
FileSystemMoveEvent('D:\temp\New Text Document.txt', 'D:\temp\foo.txt')
FileSystemCreateEvent('D:\temp\New folder')
FileSystemMoveEvent('D:\temp\New folder', 'D:\temp\bar')
FileSystemDeleteEvent('D:\temp\bar')
FileSystemDeleteEvent('D:\temp\foo.txt')
```

for the creation, rename and deletion of a plain file and folder.

(You tagged the question as Flutter Web even though you are on desktop. You obviously cannot use `dart:io` in web.)

Comment: Has anyone noticed that using cancel on the stream doesn't work? On Windows cancelling the stream using Watch.listen.cancel sill emits events. Comments on this?

Comment: It works for me. If I change above code to `final sub = tempFolder.watch().listen((event)...` then I can later call `sub.cancel()` and there are no more events.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Appreciated. Looks like a platform/sdk version specific issue my end.